# VBA - Based on identifiers, dynamically open workbooks in a directory & paste a value from each?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few hundred or so excel files in a directory each with a unique identifier somewhere in the name, 103, 208c, 231a, etc. Identifiers are housed in a column in the workbook with the code. Based on these identifiers I'm trying to dynamically open the workbook containing the string of text and paste a single cell to be next to it's workbooks identifier.

I tried to get it to work for a single case below but after the would be dynamic file opens the macro ends rather than selecting the value and pasting it. If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix that or how to switch this code from single case to dynamic/loop based I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm relatively new to coding VBA. Normally only need to rarely read it/step thru existing code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Process()
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

Dim sFound As String, fPath As String
Dim BaseFile As Workbook
Dim TestSheet As Worksheet
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Set TestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TestSheet")
Set BaseFile = ThisWorkbook

fPath = "\\WhateverDirectory\"
sFound = Dir(fPath & "*231a*") '231a should be values in column B row 4 on in the TestSheet
If sFound <> "" Then
    Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(fPath & sFound)
    WB1.Sheets("RCM").Range("D6").Copy
    BaseFile.Activate
    TestSheet.Range("C4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

Comment: Don't completely understand the question but if you just want to pick up the value from column B row 4, you could just do this: `TestSheet.Range("B4").Value`. Although I don't understand how that is **dynamic** if it's always the same cell

Comment: I meant dynamic in the sense that the workbook it will need to pull from will ultimately vary by the identifiers and not just be the *231a* I hardcoded. Ie open asdas-101-V2 copy D6 and paste next to identifier 101. Then if next identifier in the column is 108b open xyz-108b-V3 copy D6 from it and paste in the source workbook next to identifier 108b